# Flask setup using SSL and subdomain on Ubuntu server

Tags: python, flask, subdomain, ubuntu-16.04

I'm am new to Flask and trying to set up a flask webpage on the subdomain https://ohl.bhelpful.net. I have another webpage running on https://bhelpful.net that has nothing to do with this flask app.

When I enter *"service apache2 reload"* and try to go on https://ohl.bhelpful.net it just gives me this:
[image: Error when trying to view webpage]

The main website (just a plain HTML) on https://bhelpful.net looks like this:

[image: Image of main website working]

My config file looks like this:

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf**:

```
Listen 443
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

        <VirtualHost *:443>

                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

                DocumentRoot "/home/bhelpful/html"
                ServerName bhelpful.net
                ServerAlias www.bhelpful.net

                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile "/etc/ssl/bhelpful_net.crt"
                SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/ssl/private/bhelpful_net.key"

        </VirtualHost>

        <VirtualHost *:443>

                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
                ServerName ohl.bhelpful.net
                WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ohl/ohl.wsgi
                <Directory /home/ohl/Online-Help-List/app/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>

                Alias /static /home/ohl/Online-Help-List/app/static/
                <Directory /home/ohl/Online-Help-List/app/static/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/FlaskApp-error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/FlaskApp-access.log combined

                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile "/etc/ssl/bhelpful_net.crt"
                SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/ssl/private/bhelpful_net.key"

        </VirtualHost>

</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

The WSGI file looks like this:

**/home/ohl/ohl.wsgi**

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/home/ohl/Online-Help-List")

from app.help_me import app as application
```

The main flask file lays here:
**/home/ohl/Online-Help-List/app/help_me.py**

[image: Treeview of files and folders]

Answer (score 1):

Use these commands

**Give Permission**

chmod 755 /home/ohl/Online-Help-List/app/

**Edit**

/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf

**Replace**:

Order allow,deny 
Allow from all

Note:This is for Apache 2.2

**Replace with**:

AllowOverride All 
Require all granted

Note: This is for Apache 2.4+